# Hibernate Mapping Exception:Unknown Mapping Entity :Theme

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to map class Themes to themes table.

Themes.java

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;  
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Column;

public class Themes
{
private int id;
private String theme;
private int orderInfo;
public Themes(String theme,int order_info)
{
    System.out.println("OK");
    this.theme=theme;
    this.orderInfo=order_info;
}
public int getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id)
{
    this.id=id;
}

public String getTheme()
{
    return theme;
}

public void setTheme(String theme)
{
    this.theme=theme;
}

public int getOrder()
{
    return orderInfo;
}

public void setOrder(int order_info)
{
    this.orderInfo=order_info;
}
}
```

Themes.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
     "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="Themes" table="themes">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
     This class contains theme details. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <property name="text" column="text" type="string"/>
      <property name="orderInfo" column="order_info" type="int"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   </property>

   <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://localhost/content_templating_data
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
      root
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">

   </property>

   <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
   <mapping resource="themes.hbm.xml"/>
   <mapping resource="patterns.hbm.xml"/>
   <mapping resource="filler.hbm.xml"/>
   <mapping resource="sentences.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I a reading the contents from a csv file and i want it to insert in a databse using the following code.

ManageData.java

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class ManageData {
private static SessionFactory factory;
private static String csvfile="C:\\Users\\ANJANEY\\IdeaProjects\\hiveminds\\src\\file.csv";
private static String line="";
private static String splitby=",";
private static BufferedReader br=null;

private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    // create configuration using hibernate API
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.setProperty("connection.driver_class",
            "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url",
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/content_templating_data");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "root");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "");
    return configuration.buildSessionFactory();
}
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException {
    int count=0;
    try
    {
        factory=getSessionFactory();
        System.out.println("Factory Object created...");


    }
    catch (Throwable ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Failed to create Session Factory Object " + ex);
        //throw new ExceptionInInitializerError();
    }

    try {
        int order_info;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvfile));
        ManageData MD = new ManageData();

        line = br.readLine();
        int length=0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            count++;
            String[] str = line.split(splitby);
            length=str.length;

            order_info = Integer.parseInt(str[2]);

            //Adding theme details in the theme table
            Integer themeID = MD.addTheme(str[1], order_info);


        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    System.out.println("Done "+count);
}

//Method to add in theme table
public Integer addTheme(String theme,int order_info){

    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    Integer themeID = new Integer(0);

    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        Themes th=new Themes(theme,order_info);
        themeID = (Integer) session.save(th);
        System.out.println("OKAY");
        tx.commit();

    }catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return themeID;
}
```

I am getting the following error

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: Themes
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:693)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1485)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    at      org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:697)
    at ManageData.addTheme(ManageData.java:114)
    at ManageData.main(ManageData.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

Comment: Why don't you annotate the Java class directly instead of using these xml config files? In Java you can use features like auto complete so the chance to have errors is reduced. I'm not such a huge XML "fan".

Comment: Why don't you use annotations??? About your problem now. You should declare your class in persistence.xml

Comment: @MikeArgyriou: he used <mapping resource="themes.hbm.xml"/> for it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is you should add your package name into the `Themes.hbm.xml` like `<class name="my.package.Themes" table="themes">` than it works.

Another problem is that your mapping is not equivalent to your getter & setter and fields:

```
<property name="text" column="text" type="string"/>
<property name="orderInfo" column="order_info" type="int"/>
```

text does not exists change it to theme. And the orderInfo getter/setter should looks like:

```
public int getOrderInfo() {
    return orderInfo;
}

public void setOrderInfo(int order_info) {
    this.orderInfo = order_info;
}
```

Than the theme class works for me.

€dit: You can use something like that, too.

```
<hibernate-mapping package="my.package">
<class name="Themes" table="themes">
 ....
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name= "mypackage.Themes" table="themes">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains theme details. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <property name="theme" column="text" type="string"/>
      <property name="orderInfo" column="order_info" type="int"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

Comment: i have commented above the modified Themes.hbm.xml file..but the problem still exists

Comment: is the problem still alive because you mark my answer as right. If yes, you should add your "real" package to it, not "mypackage" :)

Comment: thats the name of my package "mypackage" :)